# Foreign key setup issue with DJango and Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, mysql-python

I am new to DJango and Python. Right now I am building a model that looks something like this:

Property -> Room -> Images.

- I mean to say that a user can have a property.
- Every property can have multiple rooms.
- Every room can have multiple images.

Now I set property ID as foreign key in Room model.

And Room ID as foreign key in Image model.

But when I am making a post call to insert a new image for a specific room and a specific property.

It creates a image object even though the property id does not exist. It only checks for room id.

Though the put call is executing perfectly.

I want to validate both room id and property id before inserting a new image.

Code:

```
class PropertyRoom(models.Model):
   pass
class PropertyRoom(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property,related_name='rooms')
class PropertyRoomImage(AbstractImage):
    room = models.ForeignKey(PropertyRoom, related_name='images')
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant parts of the models?

Comment: @Sayse I have added the basic model structure. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: your fk on the property room doesn't have the option to be null so therefore there must be a property for each room

Comment: Yes that true. But the problem is when I am adding an image for a specific room then it only checks for room id, I can pass any Invalid property id and still the post call executes perfectly.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could include the relevant code.. if you're adding an image to a specific room then that room has a specific property already

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/properties/221/rooms/1/images/    I am making a post call on this url for example. Room id 1 exist but property id 221 does not.

Answer (score 0):

While theoretically your database should ensure that you have correct data, there are cases when this may not be the case, (IIRC foreign keys might not be present in the database on MySQL with mixed table engines (InnoDB and MyISAM))

Assuming you use forms, you could add a [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/) to your upload form.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
    image = cleaned_data['image']
    property = cleaned_data['property']
    if image.room.property != property:
        raise ValidationError("room property and supplied property don't match")
    return cleaned_data
```

You can write the same logic for models too, but beware they are not called by `save` by default, so you would have to create them explicitly. [Official model validations documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

```
image = PropertyRoomImage()
image.room = ...
image.full_clean()   # call it explicitly as save doesn't
image.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:8000/api/properties/221/rooms/1/images I am making a post call on this url for example. Room id 1 exist but property id 221 does not.

You shouldn't need to pass the room across at all, or if you do need to then you can just ignore it, you can just create an image using the id of the room, and if you need the property, then you can access the correct room via `room.property`

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:8000/api/properties/221/rooms/1/images I am making a post
>   call on this url for example. Room id 1 exist but property id 221 does
>   not.

You need to implement this check yourself. The models don't know about all the hierarchy of your data; or your business rules.

You need to check:

1. Property exists
2. Room being referenced, belongs to that property or not.
3. Image is of correct type/dimensions; etc.

Try a pattern like this:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def api(request, room=None, property=None):
    property = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property)
    if not property.property_room_set.filter(pk=room).exists():
        raise Http404

    # other checks
    # your normal logic
```